# If $s, t$ are solutions of a system of equations, prove that $s \equiv t \pmod r$ where $r = lcm(m, n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$\newcommand{\lcm}{\operatorname{lcm}}$

> If $s, t$ are solutions of $$\begin{cases}
> x \equiv a \pmod m, \\ 
> x \equiv b \pmod n,
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   prove that $s \equiv t \pmod r$ where $r = \lcm(m, n)$

$s = a \pmod m$ and $s = b \pmod n$

$t = a \pmod m$ and $t = b \pmod n$

So,

$s - a = mk$ and $s - b = nq$

$t - a = mj$ and $t - b = nl$

Then,

$s - a - (t - a) = mk - nj = m(k - j)$

and $s - b - (t - b) = nq - nl = n(q - l)$

Thus,

$m, n \mid s - t$. Now let $s - t = q\lcm(m, n) + r$ with $0 \le r < \lcm(m, n)$. So, $r = (s - t) - q\lcm(m, n)$. Then $m, n \mid r$. If $r \neq 0$, then $r > \lcm(m, n)$ which is false. So, $r = 0$.

Does this proof work?

Comment: Yes, just a little detail in the last line. If $r\neq0$ then $r\geqslant\lcm(m,n)$ (it is not a strict inequality), but your proof is good.

Comment: At the end, just remember that for any integers $a,b,k$ we have $a,b\mid k\iff \text{lcm}(a,b)\mid k$. So in particular $m,n\mid s-t\iff \text{lcm}(m,n)\mid s-t$, and you're done.

Comment: Thank you, people. I got a little mixed up. I can't solve problems without making at least one mistake :)